# how range functions works in creating ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

How is this range function working here? It is generating an answer but I can't understand it it has created the resulted ndarray.

`np.array([range(i, i + 3) for i in [2, 4, 6]])`

Comment: What were you expecting to get out of this?

Answer (score 1):

A range is a sequence of numbers. The function range normally accepts 1-3 params `range(start, stop[, step])`. In your case the step is ommited, thus the default 1 is applied. So it is creating ranges from a given number `i` to that number +3 → `range(i, i + 3)`

The list comprehension, makes that the given number `i` will iterate over the list `[2,4,6]`, so you will create a list with 3 sublists: `[range(2,2+3), range(4,4+3), range(6,6+3)]` wich equals to `[[2,3,4], [4,5,6], [6,7,8]]`.

Finally, all is wrapped as a numpy array and the output is → `array([[2, 3, 4],[4, 5, 6],[6, 7, 8]])`

Comment: Note that `range()` doesn't actually return a list, but `numpy` will treat it like a list when it's creating the array.